# How does browser loads DOM and CSSOM partially?

Tags: html, performance, google-chrome, dom

First let me give you simple overview how it loads, then ill ask question regarding that.

**Browser Fetch HTML** => **parse html** => **create nodes** => **parse nodes and start converting them to Dom elements** => **finds style node so start creating CSSOM** => **on finishing parsing if there was style tag it waits to let it construct CSSOM tree** => **once both are finished it merges both, DOM and CSSOM, and fires `DOMContentLoaded` Event**.

So in summary as soon as CSSOM is ready browser starts rendering and Dom can incrementally be added.

This is all fine, but how does the flow go when browser starts rendering page when not the whole html is loaded..(for example in nodejs you can partial html then wait 2s and then send more)

1. What if there was another style tag at the bottom of the page. Not having received all html, and no css browser would start rendering, but from my understanding rendering only occurs after cssom has been completely built.
2. What happens to script tag, if css isn't done processing script tag isn't executed and thus also stops parsing. JS is ran after CSSOM is complete.

Comment: Rendering does not have to wait for all CSS to be available.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/analyzing-crp?hl=en#performance-patterns  according to this js and rendering happens after cssom is complete and whole reasons cssom blocks everything is that css later on can change the ouput where as dom elements loaded later on wont change output but will only add on to the dom tree

Comment: From what I understand: First.. parsing and rendering are different stages. DOM is built incrementally, meaning without having to load whole html file, it's parsed as soon as bytes arrive from connection. Not CSS, first whole css file is fetched, then parsed. Yes, CSS link/inline/embedded will block parsing. Browser will wait for CSSOM to finish.After all blocking css/scripts have been fetched executed/parsed. DOM/CSSOM has been built only then DOMContentLoaded is fired. Now styling and rendering begins. I was thinking they only block rendering, but no they block parsing.

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/building-the-dom-faster-speculative-parsing-async-defer-and-preload/

Comment: There were some misunderstandings in my understanding. JS isn't ran after ALL CSSOM is built. Only CSSOM for the encountered style tag. Script and style tags are executed in order they are declared (given not using defer/async).

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQRada

Comment: Please visit https://jackgiffin.com/main/books/Starnes-The-Practice-of-Statistics-AP-5e.html for a demonstration. Even though it is a 69MB webpage, it still presents itself to the user reasonably fast by sprinkling inline <script> elements throughout the HTML so that as soon as the page you are at has finished downloading, it is presented to the user before the rest of the webpage has loaded. Surprisingly, all browsers that I have tested have displayed the webpage before the entire file finished downloading: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, Opera Mini, and even Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: It's just the property of DOM. DOM is constructed first and then images are loaded afterwards.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer what do you mean by CSSOM for the encountered style tag? Does it mean that any style tags that have been encountered till before the script tag was encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSSOM stops parsing. Thus execution of subsequent script tags, and also delays rendering.

Script tags before style tags will execute before CSS is loaded into CSSOM from style tags afterwards.

Style tags that come after script tags will alter CSSOM. And if script accessed styles that are being altered then what it read is outdated. Order matters.

Parsing is stopped not just rendering.

> JavaScript blocks parsing because it can modify the document. CSS
>   can’t modify the document, so it seems like there is no reason for it
>   to block parsing, right?
>
> However, what if a script asks for style information that hasn’t been
>   parsed yet? The browser doesn’t know what the script is about to
>   execute—it may ask for something like the DOM node’s background-color
>   which depends on the style sheet, or it may expect to access the CSSOM
>   directly.
>
> Because of this, CSS may block parsing depending on the order of
>   external style sheets and scripts in the document. If there are
>   external style sheets placed before scripts in the document, the
>   construction of DOM and CSSOM objects can interfere with each other.
>   When the parser gets to a script tag, DOM construction cannot proceed
>   until the JavaScript finishes executing, and the JavaScript cannot be
>   executed until the CSS is downloaded, parsed, and the CSSOM is
>   available

.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/building-the-dom-faster-speculative-parsing-async-defer-and-preload/

Comment: if parsing is stopped, doesn't that mean rendering is also stopped ?

Comment: but that does not seem to be true. rendering (for whatever has already been parsed) happens even if the whole document hasn't been parsed.

Comment: yes that's correct. But I had read/misunderstood that JS is ran after all of the css on page has been parsed and applied. Which was in conflict that JS is ran after CSSOM, but answer was both are true with one difference; JS is ran after CSSOM is complete but only CSS that has come before it, it's not ALL css.

Answer (score 2):

Things may block the `DOMContentLoaded` Event, but that does not prevent rendering of the incomplete page. That can be important for very long pages streamed from a slow server.

Browsers can and do interleave script execution, re-styling, rendering with the document parsing. This can be trivially shown by executing javascript in the `<head>` and querying the DOM, you will see that the document will not have all of its nodes (possibly not even a body element) before the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired.

You have to think of document construction more as a stream than sequentially executed blocks that run to completion before the next block starts.

Comment: Isn't JS ran after CCSOM construction?

Comment: no. scripts, html parsing, css parsing all interleaves with each other, depending at which position they are in the html (and a bunch of other factors)

Comment: yea i agree they do affect each other, but there are rules which i am trying to understand, this course on udacity by google says js is ran after cssom is done getting constructed. https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud884/l-1469569174/m-1524418577

Comment: @the8472 what is the source of that affirmation? Google [specifically tells](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript) that _**the browser delays script execution** and DOM construction **until it has finished downloading and constructing the CSSOM**_

Comment: @Veehmot read the question for context. *"So in summary as soon as CSSOM is ready browser starts rendering and Dom can incrementally be added. "* is trivially wrong. Just because you don't have a complete DOM or CSSOM as defined in the context of `DOMContentLoaded` does not mean there is nothing that could be rendered, such as a partial CSS state.

Answer (score 0):

A few important facts:

- Event `DOMContentLoaded` is fired when the document has been fully parsed by the *main* parser AND the DOM has been completely built.
- Any normal script (not async or deferred) effectively blocks DOM construction. The reason is that a script can potentially alter DOM.
- Referencing a stylesheet is not parser-blocking nor a DOM-construction-blocker.
- If you add a `<script>` (be it external or inline) after referencing a CSS, the *execution* (not fetching) of the script is delayed until fetching and parsing of the CSS has been finished even if the script's fetch finishes sooner. The reason is that the scripts may be dependent on the to-be-loaded CSS rules. So the browser has to wait.
  Only in this case, a CSS blocks the document parser and DOM construction *indirectly*.
- When the browser is blocked on a script, a second lightweight parser scans the rest of the markup looking for other resources e.g. stylesheets, scripts, images etc., that also need to be retrieved. It's called "Pre-loading".

Comment: It should be noted that even if the styles are declared before the script tag, or a large css file is linked before the script tag, the `domcontentloaded` event might fire before the css styles are parsed. To fix that you'd want to do a _forced css repaint_ at the beginning of js code.